# Cmake and gcc combine

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have many source files in source directory. For example a.c, b.c, c.c and want to compile it by gcc with -combine option.

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-combine")
set(SRC a.c b.c c.c)
add_executable(a.out ${SRC})
```

Cmake compiles each *.c file in object file, but I want to compile all sources to one object. How can I get this.

In terms of gcc:

```
gcc -combine a.c b.c c.c -o module.o
ar rcs library.a module.o
```

But cmake uses per-module translation of sources.

```
gcc a.c -o a.o
gcc b.c -o b.o
gcc c.c -o c.o
ar rcs library.a a.o b.o c.o
```

Translation with combine could speed up performance of program. I couldn't use LTO which could resolve the same problem in cmake due to old version of gcc.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure an option `-combine` exists? I have a feeling that that's not what you're trying to do. Maybe you mean `-fwhole-program`, which is morally equivalent to concatenating all your source files together. But more likely you're just trying to make a reusable library. Use `-shared` to make a dynamic library, or just use the `ar` program to combine lots of `.o` files into a static library. CMake can automate both for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. This option exist in gcc version 4.4/4.5

Comment: Interesting, it disappeared in 4.6! :-) What's its purpose? Anything you can't achieve with `-fwhole-program`?

Comment: Yes, 4.6 doesn't have -combine, but our team use gcc-4.3 and 4.4. There are the same problem with -fwhole-program as for combine, because it need to compile all source files in one compilation unit to create 1 object file.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this. I'm currently using a custom Makefile system instead of CMake but I'd like to switch. But performance via inter-module optimization is more important than CMake.

Comment: By the way, anyone who wants to combine source files without `-combine` or wants to combine for c++ check this out: http://pastebin.com/fRa4MnPC

Comment: New versions of gcc supports LTO so question became obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use add_custom_target/add_custom_command.

In any way it is non-portable construction, so here simple example

[project root] with two folders in it [src] - here N files, [build] for binary, and CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.0 FATAL_ERROR)
set(TARGET_NAME whole)
project(${TARGET_NAME} C)

file(GLOB SRC_FILES src/*.c)

add_custom_target(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -flto -fwhole-program ${SRC_FILES} -o ${TARGET_NAME})
```

In build folder run cmake ..; make VERBOSE=1 whole

This will make the work for you.

But, -fwhole-program work only with executable, as per [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

> -fwhole-program
>   Assume that the current compilation unit represents the whole program being compiled. All public functions and variables with the exception of main and those merged by attribute externally_visible become static functions and in effect are optimized more aggressively by interprocedural optimizers.

So you mast have main defined anywhere in your source files.